# How to retrieve data from postgres to textbox in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I want to retrieve data from postgres db into textbox in C# without using grid.

Here is the running successful code by using grid which I had tried:

```
connection.Open();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM student_folio";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
cmd.Dispose();
connection.Close();
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I get error when build when I want to retrieve it into textbox: 
"cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'NpgsqlDataAdapter'"

Here is my block of code:

```
connection.Open();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT f_name FROM student_folio WHERE id = 1");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);

txtFname.Text = da["f_name"].ToString();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataAdapter` is not an array of rows you can loop into.
Look at your first code block : you must fill a `DataTable` from your adapter and then read through the `Rows` property of this `DataTable`.

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  txtFname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["f_name"].ToString();
}
```

You could also do this  :

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row  in dt.Rows)
{
  txtFname.Text = row["f_name"].ToString();
}
```

And please, remove the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line, it is useless here

Comment: By the way, another solution would be to use a ```DataReader``` instead of ```DataAdapter``` + ```DataTable```. It is less heavy to achieve something like this. I guess a ```NpgsqlDataReader``` class must also exist

Answer (score 0):

try this . .

```
connection.Open();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
NpgsqlDataReader dr=null;
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT f_name FROM student_folio WHERE id = 1");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.HasRows)
{
   while(dr.Read())
   {
       txtFname.Text = da["f_name"].ToString();
   }
}



connection.Close();
```